# How can I make a local API to connect to ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, flask

Hi I am trying to learn Ajax, and I want to get data from a local API that I made. So far I have a file called data.json in the same directory as all my other files. The data contains information like this:

```
{
 "username": bob900,
 "email": "bob@gmail.com",
 "password": "apples123"
}
```

I want to be able to use this file as a link in my Ajax so I want to make a route for it. Something like `http://localhost:3000/data`.

So far I have tried making a route for it with flask like:

```
@app.route("/data")
     def api():
     return data.json
```

However, when I try accessing the link it takes me to an internal server error page.

To understand more of what I am trying to do you can look at the youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEYx8dQr_cQ&ab_channel=LearnCode.academy and go to 2:59. I am trying to make an API like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. import `os` and `json` from flask

and add your path in here as

```
filename = os.path.join(file_path_here , 'sample.json')
```

for even more clarity a sample working snippet:

[image: file in static folder in my case]

Comment: the top code gave me a bunch of errors i dont know why

Comment: have you put your static directory path in place of `your_static_dir` for eg : `E:/folder/folder/myFile.json`  ? and did u import os if not on top put this line `import os`

Comment: please update what errors you got and put the code for the same ...

Comment: one of them is `NameError: name 'os' is not defined` and i put `api/data.json` instead of your_static_dir as I added an api folder to keep these files in

Comment: i have updated my answer with a work around , make sure you put exact path ..

Comment: at this point i will give you top answer because it is probably my code doing something wrong but my error now is `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'static/data.json'` for some reason it can never find my data.json file

Comment: could you please let me know where the file is placed in your directory ? please add your directory tree like ... `main_folder -- static -- sample.json` in my case and in your case it might be in different place